# Django (nonrel), App engine and asynchronous database calls

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, django-nonrel

When using Google App Engine with Django-nonrel, is there any way to take advantage of the [Async Datastore API](https://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/async.html) when I declare my model classes with the Django API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've investigated a bit more and found an alternative way to deal with having a Django Model (i.e.: all Django features there) and still having access to the async API...

Mainly, using the datastore directly:

```
from google.appengine.api import datastore
```

and I already had methods to convert all my models to/from a json dict, so, it was mostly a matter of discovering how Django-Nonrel did it behind the scenes:

E.g.:

Considering a 'Project' class with to_json and from_json methods (i.e.: create from a dictionary)

For doing a simple query (it seems Run() will do the work asynchronously, so, one could do the query.Run() and later start another query.Run() and both would work at the same time):

```
query = datastore.Query(Project._meta.db_table)
for p in query.Run():
    p['id'] = c.key().id() #Convert from app engine key
    print Project.from_json(p)
```

Now, using the API to get an object asynchronously:

```
from djangoappengine.db.compiler import create_key
async = datastore.GetAsync(create_key(Project._meta.db_table, project_id))
p = async.get_result()
p['id'] = c.key().id() #Convert from app engine key
print Project.from_json(p)
```

So, it's possible to retain the model with the Django structure and when needed some wrappers do the needed work asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

No. The Django framework provides its own interface to the datastore, and until it supports asynchronous calls directly, it's not possible to make asynchronous calls.

Comment: Ok, guess I'll have to convert my model for the App Engine model then... Although in that case I think I'd loose the Django admin -- is there something similar to that when using the App Engine database model? Or would it be possible to keep both database structures at the same time?

Comment: @Fabio You could maintain models in both libraries, but that's about the only way. The App Engine admin console provides basic add/modify/delete operations on the datastore.

Comment: Ok, I found a way to work through that (added my own answer).

Comment: I'm mystified why anyone would downvote this. It's entirely accurate.

Comment: Hi Nick, I removed my vote because I found that Django-nonrel actually does the whole mapping to the app engine datastore, so, I added an answer explaining how to do that (so, I kept the django structure and use the wrapping that nonrel already does just for that specific use-case).

Comment: @FabioZadrozny Your answer works, but it involves reaching into the innards of Django-nonrel in an undocumented fashion. In any case, I was referring to the anonymous individual who downvoted my answer without leaving a comment.